# Known Ethereum Addresses

Tags: web-scraping, ethereum

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all known ethereum or other cryptocurrency addresses?Currently building a scraper that searches an address on etherscan (https://etherscan.io/ ) and returns info. Anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: see this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/how-to-list-all-ethereum-addresses-with-a-positive-balance

Comment: Etherscan gives you a list of all accounts, I guess that's what you meant by scraping? https://etherscan.io/accounts

Comment: Yes, that is what I am currently doing.

Comment: for the see answer. I do not need all accounts that have a positive value just accounts of which the owner is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was the most useful https://etherscan.io/labelcloud; however, is not completely consistent. As in there are wallets that are classified as X which do not appear under the label X. e.g. Yobit.net does not appear on the exchange label but is classified as an exchange if you look for it manually.